# How to load data in background when app is not running on iOS 7

Tags: background-process, ios7

In iOS 7 how can a process be started and ran while the app is not running.  I want to be able to sync data to my app without user interaction.  I have heard that this is now possible in iOS 7.  Ideally I will be using APNS to start the sync in the background without the user interacting(which is impossible on iOS6).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.read more detail about this on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS7.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013162-SW5